# how to fix no matching function for call to 'atoi'?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm creating a multithreaded C program using the Pthreads API. My program basically creates a separate thread inside main, called runner, it then passes integer parameter that was provided on the command line, argv[1], to runner. Runner sums up all values from 1 to argv[1]. Sum, a global variable is printed in main.

I get the following error: no matching function for call to 'atoi'.

```
g++ -c -Werror main.cc
main.cc:30:14: error: no matching function for call to 'atoi'
        int upper = atoi(param);
                    ^~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:132:6: note: candidate function not viable: cannot convert
      argument of incomplete type 'void *' to 'const char *' for 1st argument
int      atoi(const char *);
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

**Here is my code**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum; /* this data is shared by the thread(s) */
void *runner(void *param); /* threads call this function */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t tid; /* the thread identifier */
    pthread_attr_t attr; /* set of thread attributes */
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%d must be >= 0\n",atoi(argv[1]));
        return -1;
    }
    /* get the default attributes */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    /* create the thread */
    pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,argv[1]);
    /* wait for the thread to exit */
    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
    printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
} // end of main

/* The thread will begin control in this function */
void *runner(void *param) {
    int upper = atoi(param);
    int i;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= upper; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
} // end of runner
```

Comment: You need to cast `param`, as it's `void*`: `atoi((char*)param)`

Comment: Just an FYI, if you take the time to read the error message, and look at the specific complaint, you can usually solve trivial problems like this yourself.

Comment: @TomKarzes I do before posting.

Comment: You apparently use C++, not C. Different languages, use the correct tags.

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski: It would not be required (and is discouraged) in C.

Comment: @Olaf I basically copied and pasted this code from my operating systems textbook. The title for this code is "Multithreaded C program using the Pthreads API".

Comment: @asilvester635: If that is supposed to be C, why do you use a C++ compiler? Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics! Get a good C textbook (about **modern** C, i.e. not ancient C90 or K&R) before starting with advanced stuff. (and that is not about writing an OS as the textbooks's name implies - maybe a better book for that might be helpful, too).

Answer (score -1):

Just like the comments said, the problem is you are passing `void *` instead of `char *` to your `atoi()` call.

But, if you are using C++, please use the following instead:

```
int i;
std::istringstream ss(argv[1]);
ss >> i;
if (!ss.good()) {
  // Input was not a number...
} else {
  // Use i...
}
```

Why? At least because:

- You can check if the conversion was successful (`atoi()` does not detect errors.)
- C++ style, not C style